# Python3 Bound method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i have a python file that contains the class pets and a file conatins the class people and a main file
the code is this:
the pets code:

```
class Pet:
def __init__(self, name, age, sound, type):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self. sound = sound
    self. type = type

class Dog(Pet):
def __init__(self, name, age):
    super().__init__(name, age, "How How", "Dog")


class Cat(Pet):
def __init__(self, name, age):
    super().__init__(name, age, "Mewo", "Cat")
```

this is the peoples file:

```
    import Pets
class Person:
def __init__(self, gender, name, age):
    self.gender = gender
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.pets = []

def addPet(self, pet):
    if isinstance(pet, Pets.Pet):
        self.pets.append(pet)
    else:
        print("This is not a pet pls try again.")

def printPets():
    print("He has:")
    for pet in self.pets:
        print("A: " + pet.type+ " Named: " + pet.name)
```

And this is the Main file:

```
from Person import Person
import Pets
def Main():
p1 = Person("Male", "Bob", 18)
p1.addPet(Pets.Cat("Mitzi", 2))
p1.addPet(Pets.Dog("Rexi", 5))
print(p1.printPets)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

the output that i get is:

```
<bound method Person.printPets of <Person.Person object at 0x7f413e3604e0>>
```

what is this and how do i fix it ??
thanx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is `print(p1.printPets())`

You need to **invoke** the method.

Else what you are doing is **printing** the method and what Python gives you is the method type (bound), instance type to which it belongs and address of the instance.

Comment: You could then Accept the answer to close the topic. Glad it did.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include `()` inside `print()` like this:

```
print(s1.avg())
```